# Closexml how to add multiple hyperlinks to a single cell in excel concatenated with comma

Tags: c#, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, closedxml

I have a comma separated array of clients

example of clients [1, 6 8 , 19 .....]

my code :

```
  if (columna.Orden == 4)
                {
                  var celda = _workshitActive.Cell(_rowActual, column.Orden);
                    var idClients = Clients.Split(',').ToList();
                    //celda.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
                
                    idClients.ForEach(id => {
                        var link = $"https://api.testarba.com/cliente/id";
                        if (!link.IsEmptyOrDefault())
                            celda.Hyperlink = new XLHyperlink(link);
                    });
```

the problem of this , it  generates a single hyperlink for all ids , i want each id with his own hyperlink. like  [20](https://api.testarba.com/cliente/20), [22](https://api.testarba.com/cliente/22)... in the some cell.
Is  possible?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. Can you create such a spreadsheet by using only Excel?

Comment: @FrancoisBotha  No I can't.